# Android Espresso test fails with IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am trying to learn Espresso for android. I created a simple android studio project for the purpose. But I am facing some issues while running the test case.

Here is my module level `build.gradle` file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdullah.mytestapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
}
```

My Test case is:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(new Object());
    }
}
```

The output of test run is:

```
Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.abdullah.mytestapplication.MainActivity
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.abdullah.mytestapplication.MainActivityTest.<init>(MainActivityTest.java:19)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$

----------

.run(Instrumentation.java:1970)

Finish
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this exception and how to get rid of it. The behavior is same when I run on device or emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround from [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183454) link.

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Excluding `support-v4` frm `expresso-contrib` makes it work.

---

**EDIT**

For version `2.2.2` need to do the following:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting the same error after adding the exclude line for espresso-contrib. I'm on espresso-contribL:2.2.2. Any idea why?

Comment: @clu You need to add following `exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'`

Comment: @Abdullah This answer didn't solve the problem on my side.

Comment: @X-HuMan Me neither